# Avoid Double Encoding of URL query param with Spring's RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, encoding

I'm trying to use Spring's RestTemplate::getForObject to make a request for a URL which has a URL query param.

I've tried:

- Using a string
- Creating a URI with URI::new
- Creating a URI with URI::create
- Using UriComponentsBuilder to build the URI

No matter which of these I use, encoding the url query param with URLEncoder::encode gets double encoded and using this encoding leaves the url query param unencoded.

How can I send this request without double encoding the URL? Here's the method:

```
try {
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(detectUrl)
            .queryParam("url", URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8"))
            .queryParam("api_key", "KEY")
            .queryParam("api_secret", "SECRET");
    URI uri = builder.build().toUri();
    JSONObject jsonObject = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, JSONObject.class);
    return jsonObject.getJSONArray("face").length() > 0;
} catch (JSONException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's an example:

Without URLEncoder:

```
http://www.example.com/query?url=http://query.param/example&api_key=KEY&api_secret=SECRET
```

With URLEncoder:

```
http://www.example.com/query?url=http%253A%252F%252Fquery.param%252Fexample&api_key=KEY&api_secret=SECRET
```

':' should be encoded as %3A and '/' should be encoded as %2F. This does happen - but then the % is encoded as %25.

Comment: Please provide an example URI and how it gets double encoded.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've added an example of URI double encoding.

Comment: I don't believe the URL specification requires `:` or `/` to be encoded. You should be able to use `http://www.example.com/query?url=http://query.param/example&api_key=KEY&api_secret=SECRET` directly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `UriComponentsBuilder` is a builder for `UriComponents` which

> Represents an immutable collection of URI components, mapping component type to `String` values.

The [URI specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) defines what characters are allowed in a URI. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/438154) summarizes the list to the characters

> `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`

By those rules, your URI

```
http://www.example.com/query?url=http://query.param/example&api_key=KEY&api_secret=SECRET
```

is perfectly valid and requires no additional encoding.

The method [`URLEncoder#encode(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

> Translates a string into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format using a specific encoding scheme.

That is not the same thing. That process is defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm), and `URLEncoder` (afaik) should be following it pretty closely.

In your original code, using `URLEncoder#encode` converted your input `url` into

```
http%3A%2F%2Fquery.param%2Fexample
```

The character `%` is invalid in a URI so must be encoded. That's what the `UriComponents` object constructed by your `UriComponentsBuilder` is doing.

This is unnecessary since your URI is completely valid to begin with. Get rid of the use of `URLEncoder`.

Comment: But if I have a parameter inside of the second url, then it will create problems right ?