# Springboot : Prevent double encoding of % by Resttemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Our code uses Asyncresttemplate as follows

```
String uri = http://api.host.com/version/test?address=%23&language=en-US&format=json

getAysncRestTemplate().getForEntity(uri, String.class);
```

But `%23` is double encoded in Rest template as `%2523` and the url becomes
`http://api.host.com/version/test?address=%2523&language=en-US&format=json`,
But I need to pass encoded string, It doesn't encode if I pass decoded data '#'

How can I send this request without double encoding the URL?

Already tried using UriComponentsBuilder
[Avoid Double Encoding of URL query param with Spring's RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321361/avoid-double-encoding-of-url-query-param-with-springs-resttemplate)

Comment: Follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138183/7871971

Comment: Why do you need to send `%23` in as part of this call?  A query which takes a `#` as part of it is *very* unusual.

Comment: Facing issue for this api as well
http://api.host.com/version/test?address=AA%2FAA&language=en-US&format=json
is converted to 
http://api.host.com/version/test?address=AA%252FAA&language=en-US&format=json as well

Comment: It appears that your api encodes the url. So you need to pass unencoded url and the api will encode it for itself.

Comment: URL encoded value of '#' is %23 
In the case of http://api.host.com/version/test?address=%23&language=en-US&format=json, it decodes to
 http://api.host.com/version/test?address=%2523&language=en-US&format=json
But not in the case of http://api.host.com/version/test?address=#&language=en-US&format=json

Comment: Refer to this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297215/spring-resttemplate-get-with-parameters

You need to fully use the framework - not to hack it. Also, you can try getForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String,?> uriVariables), which allows you to put uriVariables as a Map.

Comment: The issue was due to this , thus solved -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182836/resttemplate-to-not-escape-url

Answer (score 11):

The `uri` argument (of type `String`) passed to the `RestTemplate` is actually a URI *template* as per the JavaDoc. The way to use the rest template without the double encoding would be as follows:

```java
getAysncRestTemplate().getForEntity(
        "http://api.host.com/version/test?address={address}&language=en-US&format=json", 
        String.class, 
        "#"); // (%23 decoded)
```

If you know you already have a properly encoded URL you can use the method that has a `URI` as the first parameter instead:

```java
restTemplate.getForEntity(
        new URI("http://api.host.com/version/test?address=%23&language=en-US&format=json"),
        String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this by not encoding any part of it yourself, e.g use `#` rather than `%23`

Comment: But I need to send encoded data to this third party api

Comment: Use Spring's function that allows you to specify parameters (data) as Map.