# How to specify OpenID Redirect URI in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, redirect, uri, openid-connect, urlencode

I shall inform the redirect URI for an application using OpenId.

My application.yml reads:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          xxxx:
            client-id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
            client-secret: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: https://www.example.com/home
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - email
        provider:
          xxxx:
            authorizationUri: https:...
            ...
```

When I look at the generated redirect URL, I see it is not URL-encoded:

```
https://.....com/authorize
    ?response_type=code
    &client_id=...
    &scope=...
    &state=...D
    &redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/home   <---- not URL-encoded
    &nonce=...
```

I would expect:

```
    &redirect_uri=https%2A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fhome   <---- encoded
```

So I go back to the configuration, and I URL-encode it:

```
            redirect-uri: https://www.example.com/home
```

At this point, I get another problem because, who knows why, this time,
Spring tried to encode it or anyway transform the redirect URI to something
illegal (seems it gets encoded twice):

```
https://.....com/authorize
    ?response_type=code
    &client_id=...
    &scope=...
    &state=...D
    &redirect_uri=https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fhome   <---- What is %253A?
    &nonce=...
```

If I omit redirect-uri and try to hardcode it in the authorization URI,
Spring tells me that the parameter is mandatory.

The provider does **not** implement auto-discovery, and I can't find a
work-around.

Also, I am bound to Spring-boot 2.7.6 cause the compiler is Java 11.
Can anybody suggest a solution? Is this issue solved with Spring 3?

I appreciate any help anybody can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321361/avoid-double-encoding-of-url-query-param-with-springs-resttemplate), according to first answer the redirect URI **not** URL-encoded is correct in terms of [URI Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2)

The characters semicolon ans slash do **not** [need to be URL encoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2).

Still I have the problem with the provider that insists on URL-encoding them, so if anybody has a bypass suggestion it is welcome.